# Is there a way to identify a group of rows to use based on the content of those rows by date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I am looking for sets of rows per appointment date that DO NOT have "chart complete" as one of the statuses; how can I go about doing this?

I am attempting to find appointments in our system that have not yet been marked as "chart complete"; this is to identify appointments where notes have not yet been done.

I have tried using NOT EXISTS to weed out the "chart complete" statuses, but no rows return.

My code is as follows (table names changed to hide identity of actual database):

```
select x.med_rec_nbr as 'MRN', convert(date, y.appt_date) as 'Appt Date', 
z.txt_appt_time, z.txt_status, z.txt_time
from table1 x (nolock) join table2 y (nolock) on x.person_id = 
y.person_id
join table3 c (nolock) on y.person_id = c.person_id and y.enc_id = 
c.enc_id
join table4 z (nolock) on c.person_id = z.person_id and c.enc_id = 
z.enc_id
where y.appt_date >= '20161001'
order by MRN, y.appt_date desc, x.create_timestamp desc
```

Some example rows I am getting are as follows:

```
MRN             Appt Date   txt_appt_time   txt_status      txt_time
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        CHART COMPLETE  1:23 PM
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        checked out    10:35 AM
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        discharged     10:25 AM
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        with provider  10:18 AM
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        waiting for provider    10:12 AM
000000000002    2019-01-21  10:00 AM        onboarding     10:05 AM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         CHART COMPLETE  5:34 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         checked out     2:26 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         discharged      2:24 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         ready for clinical discharge     
2:15 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         with provider   2:10 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         waiting for provider    1:48 PM
000000000002    2019-01-14  1:45 PM         onboarding  1:42 PM
```

The code I am attempting to use is:

```
......
and NOT EXISTS (select x.med_rec_nbr as 'MRN', convert(date, 
y.appt_date) as 'Appt Date', z.txt_appt_time, z.txt_status, 
z.txt_time
from table1 x (nolock) join table2 y (nolock) on x.person_id = 
y.person_id
join table3 c (nolock) on y.person_id = c.person_id and 
y.enc_id = c.enc_id
join table4 z (nolock) on c.person_id = z.person_id 
and c.enc_id = z.enc_id
where y.appt_date >= '20161001' and z.txt_status = 'chart complete')
```

Expected Results:

```
0000000000002   2019-01-14     2:00 PM         waiting for provider   1:52 PM
0000000000002   2019-01-14     2:00 PM         onboarding             1:50 PM
```

and so on.

Actual results:
none

Comment: First what SQL technology are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.4000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.19266
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.8800
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: Why would the two rows in your Expected Results section be expected, since a row with that same date has "CHART COMPLETE"?  The way I read your requirements, both dates in your sample data have a "CHART COMPLETE" row, so nothing should show in the Expected Results.

Comment: I will need to provide a better example; I will have to do so on Monday 2/18.  I will update the sample rows and expected results to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Windows Aggregate:

```
with cte as
 (

    select x.med_rec_nbr as 'MRN', convert(date, y.appt_date) as 'Appt Date', 
    z.txt_appt_time, z.txt_status, z.txt_time,
    x.create_timestamp,

    max(case when pash.txt_status = 'chart complete' then 1 else 0 end)
    over (partition by x.med_rec_nbr, convert(date, y.appt_date), z.txt_appt_time) as flag

    from table1 x (nolock) join table2 y (nolock) on x.person_id = 
    y.person_id
    join table3 c (nolock) on y.person_id = c.person_id and y.enc_id = 
    c.enc_id
    join table4 z (nolock) on c.person_id = z.person_id and c.enc_id = 
    z.enc_id
    where y.appt_date >= '20161001'
 )
select *
from cte
where flag = 0
order by "MRN", "appt date" desc, create_timestamp desc
```

Comment: The only problem I seem to be having with that solution is that it does not recognize the fields I am trying to sort by; multi_part fields could not be bound, and if I leave the identifiers off, it states "invalid column".  I also tried putting the "order by" phrase inside the cte loop and got this error:  Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Update: that solution does not work; all that does is eliminate the "chart complete" from each appointment date that has that status; I only want to show those appointment dates and statuses for those dates that do not have "chart complete" in the first place.

Comment: Fixed the wrong alias names. But the expected result doesn't match your example data and I don't know if the PARTITION BY is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize my source code and use SAP Crystal Reports to filter the rows I needed.  I chose to instead use a unique identifier (encounter number) to group the appointments by, then I could utilize my flag and take out the details I didn't need.  Thank you, everyone, for your help.